# call method at runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, invocation

I am wondering if it is possible  to load a .net DLL at runtime,  view the methods available and execute one  at runtime.

If this is possible could you point me in the right direction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you use System.Reflection classes to do this task.

Specifically, you'd load the DLL via [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) (or [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx)) and then call [Assembly.GetTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) and then for each type call [Type.GetMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf.aspx). When you have a [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx), you can call [MethodInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx) on it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx).

You can call [`Assembly.LoadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile.aspx) to load a .DLL containing a .Net assembly, then call the `GetTypes` method on the returned `Assembly` object to look at the classes in the DLL.
Once you've found a `Type` object for the class you're interested in, you can call its [`InvokeMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx) method to call a function.

Beware that reflection can be quite slow.

Comment: You can improve the performance of invoking a method via reflection by using `Delegate.CreateDelegate(...)` instead of getting the method and calling it purely by reflection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx

Comment: @Dan: True.  However, that's only possible if you know the signature at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, you just start with loading your dll:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
```

And then to invoke a method inside your dll you'll have to use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxz4wk15.aspx).

```
object obj = assembly.CreateInstance(<type.FullName>);
```

where `type.FullName` is the FullName property of some type in that assembly.

Once you got your instance, you can invoke your method like this:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = obj.GetMethod("MyMethod");
methodInfo.Invoke(obj,null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this at 
[reflection eamples](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/)

```
 // get all public static methods of MyClass type
  MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Static);


[C#]
// dynamically load assembly from file Test.dll
 Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");

[C#]
// get type of class Calculator from just loaded assembly
Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("Test.Calculator");

[C#]
// create instance of class Calculator
object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);

[C#]
// get info about property: public double Number
PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo = calcType.GetProperty("Number");

[C#]
// get value of property: public double Number
double value = (double)numberPropertyInfo.GetValue(calcInstance, null);

[C#]
// set value of property: public double Number
numberPropertyInfo.SetValue(calcInstance, 10.0, null);

[C#]
// get info about static property: public static double Pi
PropertyInfo piPropertyInfo = calcType.GetProperty("Pi");

[C#]
// get value of static property: public static double Pi
double piValue = (double)piPropertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);

[C#]
// invoke public instance method: public void Clear()
calcType.InvokeMember("Clear",
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
null, calcInstance, null);

[C#]
// invoke private instance method: private void DoClear()
calcType.InvokeMember("DoClear",
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
null, calcInstance, null);

[C#]
// invoke public instance method: public double Add(double number)
double value = (double)calcType.InvokeMember("Add",
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
null, calcInstance, new object[] { 20.0 });

[C#]
// invoke public static method: public static double GetPi()
double piValue = (double)calcType.InvokeMember("GetPi",
BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
null, null, null);

[C#]
// get value of private field: private double _number
double value = (double)calcType.InvokeMember("_number",
BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
null, calcInstance, null);
```